# Downloading with node modifies excel files and causes data loss

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to create a script in node.js which will download an excel file. My code is built upon first making an `http.get` request to the URL and then write to a file using `response.pipe` and `createWriteStream`. My code is as follows:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");

let url = "http://www.functionalglycomics.org:80/glycomics/HFileServlet?operation=downloadRawFile&fileType=DAT&sideMenu=no&objId=1002183";

http.get(url, response => {
  let file = fs.createWriteStream('file.xls');
  let stream = response.pipe(file);
})
```

If you download the following file using Firefox the file downloads appropriately and if you open the file it works fine and excel does not give any errors.
http://www.functionalglycomics.org:80/glycomics/HFileServlet?operation=downloadRawFile&fileType=DAT&sideMenu=no&objId=1002183

Note- the download link above will not work with Chrome due to [this](https://www.ryadel.com/en/err_response_headers_multiple_content_disposition-error-google-chrome-fix/) issue with the filename containing `,` in filename. Therefore I cannot use puppeteer for this.

However if I use my script above and download the file and try to open it in excel it gives me an error stating "data may have been lost" 5 times but then eventually still opens the file.

[image: File error: data may have been lost error]

My question is therefore, what is causing this data loss when downloading using nodejs?

**Update**

Some data about versions:

- Node:v12.13.1
- Excel: Office 2019
- OS: Windows 10 latest

**Update 2**

Based on the comments below from jarmod, I tried using wget on Windows PowerShell. It downloads the file too but also produces the excel error.

Comment: If you use wget or curl to retrieve the file, what happens in Excel?

Comment: I am not sure. I haven't tried those. Also don't know how to try. But I need to do this in node. Are there node modules for those?

Comment: They are command line program for Mac and Linux. You can probably find Windows versions too. The point is to validate the file download using a trusted tool (like curl or wget).

Comment: I tried wget using Powershell and got a 200 OK response. I managed to save the file and opened it but it too gave me the excel error.

Comment: Same error? So it sounds like the problem is not your Node script. It's the endpoint serving the file. When I hit it, I get a ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION report which suggests that server is misbehaving.

Comment: Like I mentioned above this is because the file contains `,` in the filename. This causes the ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION error. Unfortunately I have no control over the backend. But again - how is it working fine on firefox and edge?

Comment: It works with some browsers because they've decided to be lenient when dealing with badly-formatted headers, presumably. The web server sending this should have included the filename in the header in quotes. Chrome, for whatever reason (perhaps perfectly reasonable), does not attempt to work around this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211907/discussion-between-coola-and-jarmod).

Answer (score 0):

I posted this as an [issue on the node.js github](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2615). @Hakerh400 provided a good description of what is happening there but briefly, on Windows NTFS file system there is something called ADS (Alternate-Data Streams) which keeps track of which files are downloaded from the internet to prompt security concerns. You can read more about it in [@Hakerh400 comment here.](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2615#issuecomment-615546187)

The workaround proposed is to add this `Zone.Identifier` ADS to the file after the download is complete using the following example:

```
http.get(url, response => {
  let file = fs.createWriteStream('file.xls');
  let stream = response.pipe(file);
  fs.writeFileSync(
    'file.xls:Zone.Identifier',
    `[ZoneTransfer]\r\nZoneId=3\r\nHostUrl=${url}`,
  );
})
```

Note- This workaround allows you to open the Excel file in "Protected View" without any concerns. However if you click on "Enable Editing" in the security prompt in Excel, the "File Error: data may have been lost" error still pops up (Excel 2019). However, there is no real data loss in terms of the sheets/data in cells.

I hope this answer helps anyone who faces anything similar.